# Is there a way to to use JDK tools without the use of the windows command line or an IDE?

Tags: windows, java, command-prompt

The computer lab in my High School , where I do my work for my CS course, has horribly outdated versions of java/jdk and the Netbeans IDE ( both 5.0 I believe) .

Netbeans startup takes an eternity, with frequent lockups, to the point that it interferes with my ability to hand in work on time. For this reason I used gvim to edit the .java files and compile and run them with Netbeans.

Since it's windows, I don't have the luxury of being able to just use javac  to run the files. In fact the command prompt is completely locked down on the computers for whatever reason.

Is the a way to do the work of compiling and packaging without the use of a proper IDE or the command line?

Comment: will you plz explain your problem..

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, you could write a vbscript file, prompt for the location of the java file and then execute the javac with the filename as parameter.

Comment: *"The computer lab in my High School , where I do my work for my CS course, has horribly outdated versions .. takes an eternity, .. it interferes with my ability to hand in work on time."*  It really seems like a matter that you should take up with the school.  If it affects you, it must affect other people as well, and ultimately, the use & utility of the CS course itself.

Comment: Do you have an Internet connection on school? If so, you may benefit of "online compilers" like this one: http://www.innovation.ch/java/java_compile.html

Comment: Andrew :It's a problem that my teacher is very aware of, but he has to wait for the bureaucracy  to call the 2 techs that we have in district, because he isn't allowed to make changes to the computers. 
At the moment it seems they are updating the drivers (district wide)
for the atrocious smart-board things that nobody likes using. So it is unknown when the computers will be updated

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that, but it requires a bit more work.  In Java 6, there's an API that allows you to call the compiler to compile source code. See [this link](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-1.html) for more information.

That solution assumes you have access to a Java 6 solution somehow, which I doubt very much given the version of NetBeans installed.

The other solution is of course to use something else as your environment for compiling or running the files. There's a Java editor that runs from a USB flash drive at [this link](http://www.javaeditor.org/index.php/Java-Editor)
that might just be what you are looking for. It's smaller and faster than NetBeans and I find some of my students are using it more than any other editor.  Make sure you follow the instructions for making it work from a flash drive. Also, if you don't pick the right language during installation, it defaults to German, achtung!

Comment: You're answer is awesome but you should look at Dr.Java for your students. I use it in the Comp Sci 100 class that I TA and it seems much simpler than "java-editor"

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you for bringing Dr. Java to my attention. I gave it a quick look and it's quite a nice, small and capable IDE.  The Java Editor I referred to, however, has a small visual GUI designer, I find it a bit easier to teach Swing with.  I'll be sure to give everyone a copy of Dr.Java to allow them to evaluate it for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want an IDE but [Dr.Java](http://www.drjava.org/) is a super lite IDE for java. To be honest its barely an IDE at all more like a text editor with a compiler built in. No precompiling, no code completion, and the debugger doesn't do much more than stop at breakpoints. Its used mainly as a teaching tool for java but it certainly fits what you're describing!

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own Java program that

1. Allows a developer to choose a file to compile and run.
2. Retrieves the system compiler and compiles the file.
3. Launches the compiled Java program.

Hey, I just wrote it for you.  That was tons of fun to write.  Please excuse the lack of modularity, I just hacked it out in 15 minutes.  Of course you would have to compile and package the below Java program in a .jar file that you could then double click on to run it.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;


public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Let the programmer choose the Java file to be compiled and executed.
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            int response = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File javaFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

                // Compile the Java file.
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(javaFile);
                OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(16);
                OutputStream err = new ByteArrayOutputStream(2000);
                JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
                String[] compileArgs = { javaFile.getAbsolutePath() };
                int r = compiler.run(in, out, err, compileArgs);
                if (r != 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err.toString(), "CompileError", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    // Since the file compiled successfully, run the compiled class.
                    String filename = javaFile.getName();
                    int dot = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
                    String className = filename.substring(0, dot);
                    String[] command = {
                            "javaw",
                            className,
                    };
                    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
                    pb.directory(javaFile.getParentFile());
                    pb.start();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Retrieves the system compiler and compiles the file."* That will only work if the app. is run from a JDK or the `tools.jar` is added to the run-time class-path of the app.  See the [System Requirements of the STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/#minimumrequirement) for further details.